# how to reduce rendering (quality, fps, etc) for invisible CEFSharp WinForms browser

Tags: c#, performance, winforms, optimization, cefsharp

it is possible to do? please help me with any information or solution. I need to do it for reduce processor load.
my browser is multi tab (TabControl). pages count can be 20+. some of them translating webcam one-directional stream from me.

UPD:
possible solution is ChromiumWebBrowser.Visible = false; for inactive browsers

Comment: @Luuk there is no sense in code example, but I can attach TaskManager screenshot. the streams is one-directional (from me) so...

Comment: @Luuk I've streaming 1 webcam to many sites! ok? I DO NOT viewing invisible webcam streams.

Comment: Please provide more information on the information shown on the (20+) tabs.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2922#issuecomment-623752668 tabcontrol in WinForms doesn't change the visibility of non active tabs, you can manually set the ChromiumWebBrowser.Visible property.

Comment: @amaitland thanks! so close! :) but too much. CPU load about 5% and streams works with freezes. are You have any else ideas? just for information, GoogleChrome works correct.

Comment: What do you mean streams work with freezes? How does Chrome behave exactly? Details are important as I've not seen your application and you've provided very little information. What version are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.